# How to implement dirty checking on form elements using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement dirty check on all required elements in a form

i have tried like this

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>
        userType:
    </label> 
    <input name="usertype" ng-model="userType" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userType.$dirty">Required</span><br> 
    <label>
        designation:
    </label> 
    <input name="designation" ng-model="Designation" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.Designation.$dirty">Required</span><br>    
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at documentation for ngModelController. For 1.3 there is $touched and for all version `$pristine`

Comment: can u please show a working fiddle for the same

Comment: Check the section "Binding to form and control state" in the dev guide https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/docs/guide/forms

Comment: correct syntax is $dirty  : myForm.Designation.$dirty